# Insert a new table into a word document who contains already two tables

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am using c# to develop the function, I have a word document who contains already 2 tables inside, I wish to insert a new one in the beginning of this document using the following code:

```
object start = Type.Missing;
object end = Type.Missing;
start = 0; end =0;
Word.Table titleTable = doc.Tables.Add(doc.Range(start,end), 1, 1, ref unknown, ref unknown);
titleTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Table title";
```

The problem is that this doc starts with a table, so every time when the doc was opened , the cursor stays in the cell(1,1) of this table, the table I try to insert is always positioned in the cell(1,1) of the first table.

I need some help for this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help u.. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850841.aspx